# Laplace Transform of product of modified Bessel and natural logarithm function

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions

I encounter this problem during one of my research and I do not know how to calculate this.
Find the Laplace transform of the following function:

$$
f(x) = ln(x)I_{0}(2 \sqrt x)
$$

where $ I_0 $ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Do you want to know the answer or the way to the answer?

Comment: For now, I need to know the answer. However, it will be great if I have the whole solution. Thank you for your concern!

Comment: The answer is:

$$-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\text{s}}}\left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{\text{s}}\right)+2\ln\left(\text{s}\right)\right)}{\text{s}}$$

According to WolframAlpha